# how to fire OnDragDrop event in Win form

Tags: c#

we have a picturebox control on win form. We want to fire ***OnDragDrop Event*** of label control , while drag label control over picture box control.

We have two issue 
1. how to fire Label control OnDragDrop Event 
2. Customize the Picture box Properties

We following line of code

```
this.DragDrop +=new DragEventHandler(LABEL_DragDrop);
public   void LABEL_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e){
    MessageBox.Show("label drag drop");
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Customize the Picture box Properties"? What is the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough to simply provide an event handler for the dragdrop event.
You need to enable draganddrop for the control being dragged to.
More information can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984430(v=vs.71).aspx

- In the Properties window, set the AllowDrop property to true.
- In the DragEnter event for the control where the drop will occur, use an If statement to do type-checking to ensure the data being dragged is of an acceptable type
- In the DragDrop event for the control where the drop will occur, use the GetData method to retrieve the data being dragged.

I suspect you did not follow this procedure though correctly. Step 1 and 2 alone is not enough.